# command that display the directory and the files inside that directory like a tree

Tags: linux, directory-structure, software-rec

To get information about a directory we should use a certain command, so what command that display the directory and the files inside that directory like a tree in Linux? Thank you.

Comment: Your friend here is `man tree`.

Comment: like which command can be used here ?

Comment: The `man` command tells you about the command you give it as an argument. `man tree` tells you about the `tree` command. (`man man` tells you about the `man` command.) It starts **tree - list contents of directories in a tree-like format**. And it goes on to describe 49 options. As I don't know what output you want to see, I expect you to read the man page.

Answer (score 1):

The command that you want is `tree`.

From the `man` page itself:

```
tree - list contents of directories in a tree-like format.
```

To give an example of how it works, this the command run from inside `~/Documents`:

```
.
└── test-files
    ├── a.deb
    ├── a.rpm
    ├── a.txt
    ├── folder
    |   ├── a.rpm
    |   ├── b.rpm
    │   ├── c.rpm
    │   └── d.rpm
    ├── fqdn
    ├── log
    ├── log.txt
```

From there, it shows the current working directory, `~/Documents`, as `.`

Inside there is a directory called `test-files`. Within it are several documents with the first few being `a.deb`, `a.rpm`, and `a.txt`. Also inside is a directory called `folder` and within that, there are four files called `a.rpm`, `b.rpm`, `c.rpm, and` d.rpm`.

You can see the `man` page for more options such as `-d` for listing directories only and `-f` for printing the full path prefix.

Comment: Thank you it is clear now

Comment: @joeblood Then you can accept the answer. That way, it will help other people.

Comment: Now, about those 49 options ...